# Create a custom function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I need help with creating a custom function in R.

I don't know how to create a function Y, where the 3 inputs of the function must be: n as in integer, mu (dimension m) as a vector, and sigma as a matrix (dimension mxm).

Does anyone know how to do that or have any idea of how can I reach it?

Thank you all :)

Note: I know how to create functions where the inputs are integers, but I have no idea how to proceed in this case

Comment: `my_function<- function(n,mu,sigma){code here}`. You will likely need to provide what you've tried and what the function should do.

Comment: You can pass collections of different types of objects to functions in R.  You can also return multiple objects of different types in R by storing them in a list and returning the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFun <- function(x,y,z) 
{
  # write a custom function
  x*y*z 
}
output1 <- MyFun(1,2,3) 
output1
```